# ClickOnce applications and Windows 8 certification

Tags: .net, windows-8, clickonce, app-certification-kit

Is it possible to have a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application certified as compatible with Windows 8?

Note that I’m not referring to getting the application certified for the [Windows Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Store). I just would like to have it certified as a compatible Windows 8 desktop application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, ClickOnce applications can't be certified.  :(

Here is the official word from the team:

> ClickOnce deployment manages install/uninstall a bit different than a traditional installer. For instance, install location doesn’t go to %ProgramFiles% as mandated by the desktop certification requirements, short cuts have a different extension used by Windows app e.g. *.lnk, and so forth. The result is these apps aren’t properly detected by ACK, and hence cannot be certified.

For non-ClickOnce desktop applications, check out *[Get your desktop app compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd535817)* on how to get your desktop application ready and certified. Also look at the left menu sidebar (specifically *[Windows 8 and Windows RT Compatible Logo Usage Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj591630.aspx)*). This gives you the ability to display the “Windows 8 Compatible” logo on your application since it is certified as compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  From there I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh749939 which lists the requirements.  10.1 says 'Your app must be installed in the Program Files folder by default'.  ClickOnce Apps are only installed to the User folder.  Is this a problem?

Comment: Good question.  I just sent email to find out for sure for you.  :)  Stay tuned...

Comment: Any news about this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry it is taking so long!  I was referred to two other people, and am following up with them, but I'm still on this...

Comment: I've heard back from the team, and updated my response accordingly.  ClickOnce apps can't be certified.

Comment: This is absolutely ridiculous. I just spent $200 on a code-signing cert and a MS developer account only to find out that ClickOnce (a recommended deployment mechanism from MSFT) is not supported?! I cannot describe my frustration...